# vbscript runs in excel but not in notepad

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Following script runs successfully in excel but throws syntax error when executed through .vbs file or in winautomation. I'm new to vb, please help.

```
Sub Test()
sUser = "TheUserName"
sDN = "uid=" & sUser & ",o=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=it"
sRoot = "LDAP://MyLDAPServer/o=users,dc=MyDomain,dc=it"

Dim oDS: Set oDS = GetObject("LDAP:")

On Error GoTo AuthError
Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDS.OpenDSObject(sRoot, sDN, "ThePassword", &H200)
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Login Successful"
Exit Sub

AuthError:
If Err.Number = -2147023570 Then
   MsgBox "Wrong Username or password !!!"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: Syntax error in this line on char 15  - `On Error GoTo AuthError`
Error code - 800A03EA

Answer (score 2):

From [Handling Errors in VBScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675540.aspx).

> <sup>There is little difference between the methods used in Visual Basic and those used with VBScript. The primary difference is that VBScript does not support the concept of error handling by continuing execution at a label. In other words, **you cannot use On Error GoTo in VBScript**. Instead, use On Error Resume Next and then check both Err.Number and the Count property of the Errors collection, as shown in the following example: (example not provided here - use link for example)</sup>

So you will require your own error handling code section.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDS.OpenDSObject(sRoot, sDN, "ThePassword", &H200)
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 0:
        'ERROR_SUCCESS - do nothing
    Case -2147023570
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description &Chr(10) & "Wrong Username or password !!!"
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
    Case Else
        'deal with other errors
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
End Select
```

More on getting error information at [Information.Err Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.err.aspx).